# Integrate soundtouch library in Android Studio project

Tags: android, pitch-shifting, soundtouch

I am trying to integrate soundtouch library for change in pitch and playback  rate of wav audio file. But when i add it in the project the an error arising which is given belo

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
/home/qwork/Android/android-ndk-r17/build/core/init.mk
Error:(537) *** Android NDK: Aborting...    .  Stop.
Error:(537) *** 
Error:(537) *** 
Information:BUILD FAILED
Information:Total time: 14.586 secs
Information:3 errors
Information:0 warnings
Information:See complete output in console

Please help me for resolve this issue.

Comment: how are you doing it?

Comment: first i integrate ndk in android studio then import the native source code for audio file pitching and set playback speed from this url https://gitlab.com/soundtouch/soundtouch and follow the process for integrate this library which is given from that url.

Comment: For Android project, the top level is gradle build scripts; C/C++ modules built via adding hooks ( CMake or ndk-build ) into the gradle scripts.  Open Android Studio, Create a new project with the given template and enable the C/C++, when it completes, build and run it; then add your soundtounch to your app/build.gradle file.

Comment: I create the new project but my question is how to integrate that library in app/build.gradle, i mean put it inside jni or cpp folder or only gradle file. I don't understand the importing process of this library.

Comment: Maybe check the merge request: https://gitlab.com/soundtouch/soundtouch/merge_requests. It should work -- use Android Studio's "open existing project" option, and explore and point it to build.gradle

Comment: It support now on Android studio but the app module not contain so the sample project inside soundtouch library is not running and show this error Gradle 'Android-lib' project refresh failed
Error:Expected caller to ensure valid ABI: MIPS

Comment: NDK does not support MIPS anymore, could you download the latest Android studio ( 3.1.4 ), it should not ask for MIPS anymore.  also do a git clean -xdf to make sure get fresh code ( mainly about .externalNativeBuild dir )

Comment: I download the latest Android studio (3.1.4). But when integrate soundtouch required folders inside cpp folder and make changes in native-lib then these issues occurring :-  Build command failed.
Error while executing process /home/qwork/Android/Sdk/cmake/3.6.4111459/bin/cmake with arguments {--build /home/qwork/Documents/FirstWallNew/app/.externalNativeBuild/cmake/debug/armeabi-v7a --target native-lib}
[1/2] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/native-lib.dir/src/main/cpp/native-lib.cpp.o
[2/2] Linking CXX shared library ../../.././build/intermediates/cmake/debug/obj/armeabi-v7a/libnative-lib.so

Comment: for this one, do not use CMake: you already have ndk-build method, just use that. Android studio supports it. They are enabled at relatively the same time.  Make sure you SDK and NDK is configured for your android studio, my merge_request should work. Or add a local.properties to your top level directory to set up sdk.dir = your-sdk-location and ndk.dir=ndk-location ( it will do the same thing )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General steps to converting previous projects to the latest Android Studio projects

1. Configure Android Studio to use the latest SDK and [NDK](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/#download-ndk)
2. [Convert](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate) with Android Studio: file > import or "welcome page" > "Import project"; allow Android studio to download needed packages for this project.
3. Adding your existing Android.mk/Application.mk to your newly generated app/build.gradle

   ```
   android {
   ... // other autogenerated things, no need to change
   defaultConfig {
       ...
       // manually add your existing Application.mk with relative path to the
       // directory where THIS build.gradle is. Normally it could be
       // src/main/cpp/Application.mk as the build.gradle is at "app" dir.
       // Note that the configure items inside Application.mk could all be
       // directly set in "arguments" here ( "APP_STL=c++_static" etc)
       externalNativeBuild.ndkBuild {
           arguments "NDK_APPLICATION= src/main/cpp/Application.mk"
       }
   }

   // connect to the existing project's ndk-build build file, android.mk;
   // again, with the path that is relative to THIS build.gradle file's location.
   externalNativeBuild {
       ndkBuild {
           path 'src/main/cpp/Android.mk'
       }
   }
   ```
4. Linking dependent source code modules: open Android.mk, check all source files for this module and all dependent modules are still in the right location; if not, change the path in Android.mk or copy them into the required place. This is because the converting tool does not handle dependent source files and modules.
5. Finally do a build: build > build APK ( do it twice )

   This should get you to a good position. Another useful thing might be the [`sourceSet` property](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-tips#change-default-source-set-configurations) which allow you to change project's default directories

For this SoundTouch project, [migrating it to gradle build](https://gitlab.com/soundtouch/soundtouch/merge_requests/6) in the original repo is the right approach.

Hope this helps.